# How to use an enum value in an :if validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums, ruby-on-rails-5

Suppose that we have an enum

```
enum status: { pending: 0, finished: 1, extended: 2 }
```

And we want to create a validation based on the value of the enum status

```
validates_presence_of :explanation, if: ...enum status is equal to "extended"
```

I've been brute force, trying many combinations but can't seem to find anything that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can evaluate your field using `pending?`

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: [ :active, :archived ]
  validates_presence_of :explanation, if: Proc.new { |a| a.extended? }
end
```

**Complete example  :**

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: [ :active, :archived ]
end

# conversation.update! status: 0
conversation.active!
conversation.active? # => true
conversation.status  # => "active"

# conversation.update! status: 1
conversation.archived!
conversation.archived? # => true
conversation.status    # => "archived"

# conversation.status = 1
conversation.status = "archived"

conversation.status = nil
conversation.status.nil? # => true
conversation.status      # => nil
```

**Reference:**
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Answer (score 2):

Short version:

```
validates_presence_of :explanation, if: 'extended?'
```

Comment: Nice! This works with a symbol too: `if: :extended?`.